# How do I copy a column of numbers to another column while excluding cells with zero or blank?

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-excel

I have a column containing zeros, blanks, and numbers greater than zero.  I want to copy just the cells containing numbers greater than zero to another column of contiguous cells (no placeholder cells for the non-copied ones).  How do I do that?

Comment: Does the below resolve your problem or did I overlook any constraints?

Answer (score 1):

I think the [advanced filter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-HP010073942.aspx) will do the trick.

[image: Advanced filter set-up]